# Why ReactJS file size is about 138mb?

Tags: reactjs, file, size

I am currently learning ReactJS, I have an issue installing **npx create-react-app** it takes too long to install the packages and when it's all done the **file size about 138mb**. why this is so huge?

how to reduce the file size to fasten the installing process?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Here is some information regarding this, but im not sure how far this can be extended:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/custom-templates/

And also this thread:
[npx create-react-app takes too long every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64290462/npx-create-react-app-takes-too-long-every-time)